# querySelector is unreachable inside object

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm building out an object based approach to my modal and I'm trying to convert all of the existing jQuery into pure JavaScript calls and I'm having some issues.

So here is a basic foundation that I have:

```
// Initialize modal
let modal = {

// Define an element for namespacing / This will be class based.
    el: null,

    settings: {

        // Define the title
        title: null,

        // If it has a cogwheel or not
        cogwheel: false,

        // Cogwheel trigger
        cogwheel_trigger: '',

    },

    /**************************************************************************/

    header_el: function() {
        // Break down into title/cogwheel?
        // The close button was removed in top right corner
    },

    body_el: function() {
        // Will it be a container?
        // Will there be levels/columns?
    },

    footer_el: function() {
        // What buttons will be included?
        // Do we data target the Save/Close separately?
        // What buttons should we provide?
    },

    /**************************************************************************/

    // Find the modal parent/child.
    findAncestor: function() {
        // Empty
    },

    // Show the modal
    show_modal: function() {
        // Empty
    },

    // Close the modal
    close_modal: function() {
        // Empty
    },

    /**************************************************************************/
    // Controls: Things the user can interact with.

    cogwheel_ctrl: function() {
        // Empty
    },

    add_icon_ctrl: function() {
        // Empty
    },

    remove_icon_ctrl: function() {
        // Empty
    },

    add_button_ctrl: function() {
        return modal
            .body_el()
            document.querySelector('[data-ctrl="add-button"]');
    },

    save_button_ctrl: function() {
        return modal
            .footer_el()
            .find('[data-ctrl="save-button"');
    },

    close_button_ctrl: function() {
        return modal
            .footer_el()
            .find('[data-ctrl="close-button"');
    },
}
```

For some reason, when using the jQuery `.find()` call, it all works great, but when calling on a JS alternative using document.querySelector I get a `unreachable code` error as shown below:

[image]

Could someone explain to me the what the major difference is on the .find() call and traditional JS?

Comment: Your return statement causes that issue. you are returning `model.body_el()` so the next line will never be executed. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The difference (your question), is that the find method is _chained_ onto the `.footer_el()` call, but the `document.querySelector()` is not. The result of _chaining_ makes it a single call instead of two separate calls.

Comment: Presuming that `modal.body_el()` returns a DOM element object, all you have to do is chain on the `querySelector()` statement. Like this: `return modal.body_el().querySelector('[data-ctrl="add-button"]')`

Comment: Thanks so much Randy! That is some good knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This is because with JQuery you're chaining the methods (join them), so, you're returning only one thing.

With the Vanilla JavaScript, you are not chaining the methods (and you can't chain JQuery methods with Pure JavaScript methods. So, you are returning the `modal.body_el()` and after calling the querySelector, but you can't call querySelector because you already returned something.

**Solution:**

Either use only JQuery methods or only pure JavaScript methods when returning.

Comment: OP is converting from jQuery.